# How to Connect Jhipster Front-End with Back-End in different server

Tags: jhipster

`CLOSED`

Im use proxy_pass nginx.

---

I have 2 different servers, 1 server I install a jhipster frontend and 1 server I install a jhipster back-end.

how do I connect the jhipster frontend with the back-end.

Because every time I enter the front-end page at `localhost:9000`, I always redirect to the page `localhost:8080/login`. an error appears "The site can't be reach".

dev setup:

**Back-End**, using `docker-compose`

`authentication is AUTH 2.0 using keycloak : 192.168.99.177:9080
jhipster-register : 192.168.99.177:8761
postgres : 192.168.99.177:5432`

**Front-End**, using `npm start`

`angular 7 : localhost:9000`

please help me, which part of the configuration should I change.

thank you

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. Have you read the official doc? https://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/ Is your question about dev or prod setup? What is the authentication type you selected  when generating your project ?  How are you running frontend and backend ?

Answer (score 0):

Set **SERVER_API_URL** constant in **webpack.common.js**

In your case it would look like this:

```
SERVER_API_URL: `'https://192.168.99.177:8761/'`
```